# Why I'm not getting back the new value of useState - React.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the line setVotedPosts([...previousVotedPosts, postId]);

I'm trying to get the previous value of votedPosts, but I'm getting back the newest value.

full code : https://github.com/silvertechguy/reddit-clone/blob/main/src/components/vote-buttons.js

App live : https://reddit-clone-official.vercel.app/

```
const VoteButtons = ({ post }) => {
  const [isVoting, setVoting] = useState(false);
  const [votedPosts, setVotedPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const votesFromLocalStorage =
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("votes")) || [];

    setVotedPosts(votesFromLocalStorage);
  }, []);

  const handleDisablingOfVoting = (postId) => {
    const previousVotedPosts = votedPosts;
    setVotedPosts([...previousVotedPosts, postId]);

    localStorage.setItem(
      "votes",
      JSON.stringify([...previousVotedPosts, postId])
    );
  };

  const handleClick = async (type) => {
    setVoting(true);

    // Do calculation to save the vote.
    let upVotesCount = post.upVotesCount;
    let downVotesCount = post.downVotesCount;

    const date = new Date();

    if (type === "upvote") {
      upVotesCount = upVotesCount + 1;
    } else {
      downVotesCount = downVotesCount + 1;
    }

    await db.collection("posts").doc(post.id).set({
      title: post.title,
      upVotesCount,
      downVotesCount,
      createdAt: post.createdAt,
      updatedAt: date.toUTCString(),
    });

    // Disable the voting button once the voting is successful.
    handleDisablingOfVoting(post.id);

    setVoting(false);
  };

  const checkIfPostIsAlreadyVoted = () => votedPosts.includes(post.id);
```

Comment: `previousVotedPosts` - this will refer the value of the state before you call `setVotedPosts` function to update the state. Which previous value of `votedPosts` are you trying to access?

Comment: Ater I update the state (setVotedPosts) and trying to get the updated state I always get back an empty array.

Comment: State is updated asynchronously, component will only see the updated state after a re-render. Use `useEffect` hook if you want to log the updated state.

Comment: Is there a way I can prevent the useEffect hook to run in the first time?

Comment: I wanna run useEffect every time votedPosts changes by adding it to the dependency array of useEffect. But I don't wanna run it the first time.

Comment: No, you can't prevent `useEffect` from executing after the initial render.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

`const previousVotedPosts = votedPosts;`

In JavaScript, arrays are reference types, so you can't just create a new copy of an array using `=`.

#### Try this solution

Clone array using spread syntax(`...`).

```
  const handleDisablingOfVoting = (postId) => {
    const previousVotedPosts = [...votedPosts];
    setVotedPosts([...previousVotedPosts, postId]);

    localStorage.setItem(
      "votes",
      JSON.stringify([...previousVotedPosts, postId])
    );
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Every time I try to add something to localStorage the new value overwrites the existing one in the localStorage. That's the main problem for me and what got me here to ask the main question.